# Array to string conversion error in PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting array to string conversion error , and also here i am able to get first value from database

```
                    <label for="#" class="col-sm-2 control-label">test</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php 
                    $c_box1=$c_box2=$c_box3=$c_box4=$c_box5='';
                     // $chk_box_data is which is from DB
                    foreach($selectdata as $r)
                    {
                      $list=explode(',',$r->facilities);
                      echo $list;

                      if($list=='1'){$c_box1='checked';}
                      if($list=='2'){$c_box2='checked';}
                      if($list=='3'){$c_box3='checked';}
                      if($list=='4'){$c_box4='checked';}
                      if($list=='5'){$c_box5='checked';}
                    }
                    ?>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox5" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1" <?php echo $c_box1;?>><label for="checkbox5" >check</label></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="2" <?php echo $c_box2;?>><label for="checkbox1">check</label></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="3" <?php echo $c_box3;?>><label for="checkbox2">check</label></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="4" <?php echo $c_box4;?>><label for="checkbox3">check</label></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="5" <?php echo $c_box5;?>><label for="checkbox4">check</label></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: `$list=explode(',',$r->facilities);` this line will give you an array. and you are treating as a string `if($list=='1'){$c_box1='checked';}`. That's why you are getting error

Comment: whats the output of `var_dump($r->facilities);` - post it pls

Comment: string(3) "1,2"

Answer (score 1):

The return value of explode will be an array always. So after the line  `$list=explode(',',$r->facilities);` , the `$list` will be an array which is then taken in the line `if($list=='1'){$c_box1='checked';}` as a string for comparison, that returned the error.

Answer (score 0):

`$list=explode(',',$r->facilities);` this line will give you an array. and you are treating as a string `if($list=='1'){$c_box1='checked';}`. That's why you are getting error

you can use `if(in_array("1", $list)){$c_box1='checked';}`, `if(in_array("2", $list)){$c_box2='checked';}` and so on...

```
<?php
    $c_box1=$c_box2=$c_box3=$c_box4=$c_box5='';
    $list=explode(',',"1,3,11,12,5");
    if(in_array("1", $list)){$c_box1='checked';}
    if(in_array("2", $list)){$c_box2='checked';}
    if(in_array("3", $list)){$c_box3='checked';}
    if(in_array("4", $list)){$c_box4='checked';}
    if(in_array("5", $list)){$c_box5='checked';}
?>


<div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox5" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1" <?php echo $c_box1;?>><label for="checkbox5" >check</label></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="2" <?php echo $c_box2;?>><label for="checkbox1">check</label></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="3" <?php echo $c_box3;?>><label for="checkbox2">check</label></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="4" <?php echo $c_box4;?>><label for="checkbox3">check</label></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="5" <?php echo $c_box5;?>><label for="checkbox4">check</label></div>
```

Comment: if(in_array("1", $list)){$c_box1='checked';}
        if(in_array("2", $list)){$c_box1='checked';}
        if(in_array("3", $list)){$c_box1='checked';}
        if(in_array("4", $list)){$c_box1='checked';}
        if(in_array("5", $list)){$c_box1='checked';}

Comment: is there any problem problem with explode syntax.

Comment: are you getting values in `$r->facilities`?

Comment: while i printing that value it shows only " array "

Comment: what do get output in that?

Comment: no only it shows the word " array " and this 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: package/package_edit.php

Line Number: 213

Comment: try output using `print_r()`

Comment: if you are getting array when `print_r($r->facilities)` then why you are exploding value?

Comment: paster you complete code here https://pastebin.com/ and give me link of that code